# AWS Cognito authenticating in Mac OS

Tags: swift, macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've created iOS app with Cognito authentication. It works and Cognito service is good enough.
But I need to integrate Cognito in OS X app now with same user pool. I'm very frustrating that AWS doesn't provide OSX SDK. 
I've been trying for several days to solve it. But no any luck.
- Non official SDK https://github.com/swift-aws/aws-sdk-swift/ - no appropriate SDK for OS X
- Thought about REST API - got problems with generating hash secret
- even tried fetch token from the web page

Anyone could implement Cognito authenticating in OS X app?
Have idea to develop python/php/java web app and send requests to own app and authenticate users there.

Comment: Super strange that AWS not officially supporting macOS. Even Firebase has a partial macOS support.

Comment: Yes I solved it by developing Lambda python authenticating. OS X app sends username and password and got token in response.

Comment: Similar thing on my side. I made lambdas in node.js to support SignIn, SIgnUp, ForgotPassword, etc user flows.

Comment: I am able to use HTTP API for authentication which seems to be working but too bad have to do a lot for using S3 - its frustrating indeed ;(